# Complex MySQL Query who can solve?

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

I have the following tables:

```
Material
material_ID | material_Name
A           | Sugar
B           | Flour
C           | Egg Yolk
D           | Water
E           | Tea Powder

Product
product_ID  | product_Name | material_ID    
1           | Cake         | A              
1           | Cake         | B              
1           | Cake         | C
2           | Tea          | D
2           | Tea          | E
2           | Tea          | A              

ScaleData
record_ID   | product_ID     | material_ID  | Weight
1001        | 1              | A            | 30
1002        | 1              | B            | 11
1003        | 1              | C            | 25
1004        | 1              | A            | 31
1005        | 1              | B            | 25
1006        | 2              | D            | 15
1007        | 2              | E            | 20
1008        | 2              | E            | 21
```

As you can see: product no 1 is cake and it require material: A, B, and C in order to form a complete product. Product no 2 is tea and it require material: D, E, and A to form a complete product.

```
From the weighing table (ScaleData) we can see that there is 1 cake and 0 tea. 

record_ID: 1001, 1002, 1003 creates one complete cake.
record_ID: 1004, 1005 are remaining incomplete cake ingredients.
record_ID: 1006, 1007, 1008 are remaining incomplete tea ingredients.

Question:
A. How can i create the following result table based on data from above tables:

Result
product_ID  | product_Name  | Qty
1           | Cake          | 1
2           | Tea           | 0


B. How can i display the remaining ingredients like below?

Remaining
record_ID   | product_ID   | material_ID  | Weight
1004        | 1            | A            | 31
1005        | 1            | B            | 25
1006        | 2            | D            | 15
1007        | 2            | E            | 20
1008        | 2            | E            | 21
```

EDIT: I am currently able to solve this with a mix of .NET Code + SQL Query. What I am looking for is pure SQL Query solution. My current method is as follows:

```
1. Execute: "SELECT DISTINCT product_ID FROM Product" to get a list of Product_ID.

2. Iterate through each product_ID and retrieve list of material from each product.
   Something like: "SELECT material_ID FROM Product WHERE product_ID=1"

3. Scan ScaleData table for each material and get the total row counts
   Something like:
   TotalA = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ScaleData WHERE product_ID=1 AND material_ID='A'
   TotalB = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ScaleData WHERE product_ID=1 AND material_ID='B'
   TotalC = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ScaleData WHERE product_ID=1 AND material_ID='C'

4. Compare variables: TotalA, TotalB, TotalC and get the lowest value.
   Lets say TotalA = 2 ; TotalB = 2 ; TotalC = 1
   LowestCount = TotalC = 1

5. Then we can tell total Qty for product 1 is 1 ( based on lowest count ).
   Remaining for Material A = 2 - 1 = 1
   Remaining for Material B = 2 - 1 = 1
```

That is my current solution and I know it is not very efficient. I prefer pure SQL solution and I hope some SQL Gurus are willing to help me..

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: provide the DDL and DML for the above tables and records.

Comment: I am able to accomplish it with a mix of .net code + SQL Query. But since I am not an expert with MySQL, I am asking if it is possible to accomplish it in pure SQL solution. I can post my solution algorithm but I have no idea in doing it in pure MySQL..

Comment: @AlbertTobing First one is doable (obviously), the second part is fairly complex in pure SQL. Probably better done in a stored procedure than a single query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do the first part. It could probably be cleaned up, but what it basically does is to take the ingredient there is least of per product, and that'll be the number of products you can make.

```
SELECT product_id,product_name, min(c) Qty
FROM
(
  SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, p.material_id, count(sd.product_id) c
  FROM product p
  LEFT JOIN scaledata sd
    ON p.product_id=sd.product_id
   AND p.material_id = sd.material_id
  GROUP BY product_id, p.product_name, p.material_id
) a
GROUP BY product_id
```

I made an [SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79046/7) for anyone with time to write the second part ;)

Comment: Wow. I didn't know such convenient tools exist. Thanks for sharing the link to SQLfiddle. And again WOW, you solved the first part so fast ! I've been playing around with SQL query and stuck for hours. You are really a genius !! Thank you very much !!

Comment: If there is more people like Joachim and less John Conde..